# How to get ns records that are registered to ip adress

Tags: dns, ip, whois, nameservers, nslookup

I have ip ranges.

I would like to find ns addresses that are pointing to corresponding ip adress

I'm looking for a command to do over nslookup or dig

Expected result

http://reports.internic.net/cgi/whois?whois_nic=70.84.87.146&type=nameserver
http://dnsquery.org/nswhois/85.17.137.148

How can I do that over nslookup or dig?

Or are there any solution to have such results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have that information from DNS tools like nslookup or dig.

This is because there is no such DNS query to list this information. The way that web page works is by asking the WHOIS database from a certain WHOIS server (in this case, it is Internic's WHOIS database). A certain WHOIS database usually only contains entries for some domains (like aaa.com, bbb.net), but no entries for subdomains (like xxx.aaa.com), or for other TLDs not managed by that domain registrar (like aaa.gov, bbb.us, ccc.co.uk, ddd.fr, eee.de).

There is a CLI utility (called 'whois', available in most Linux distributions) to access the WHOIS database. You will have to specify the name or address of the WHOIS server (whois.internic.net in this case), and the query in a format understood by that WHOIS server. For example:

```
whois -h whois.internic.net 70.84.87.146
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply but I could not list ns addresses with this tool. whois -v 70.84.87.146 whois.internic.net / what could be problem with my command.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply but I could not list ns addresses with this tool. whois -v 70.84.87.146 whois.internic.net / what could be problem with my command

Comment: I don't know Windows tools, I use Linux.
You can try other Windows whois tools (google is your friend): http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/jwhois.htm http://www.gena01.com/win32whois/